# Send file encrypted (Server) and receive file decrypted (Client) with AES 256

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

Im sending a file from Server to a Client but i need to send a encrypted file with AES 256 and receive a original for client use in diferente machine.
I want use 2 string to generate a SHA256 for example: "fruit" and "car29".
After generate this key I want to use this key as secretkey to encrypt with AES256.The client and server know the two strings.

My server code:

```
public final static int SOCKET_PORT = 4444;
public final static String FILE_TO_SEND = "C:\\file.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    ServerSocket servsock = null;
    Socket sock = null;
    try {
        servsock = new ServerSocket(SOCKET_PORT);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting...");
            try {
                sock = servsock.accept();
                System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);
                // send file
                File myFile = new File(FILE_TO_SEND);
                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
                fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                os = sock.getOutputStream();
                System.out.println("Sending " + FILE_TO_SEND + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
                os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                os.flush();
                System.out.println("Done.");
            } finally {
                if (bis != null) {
                    bis.close();
                }
                if (os != null) {
                    os.close();
                }
                if (sock != null) {
                    sock.close();
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (servsock != null) {
            servsock.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My client code:

```
public final static int SOCKET_PORT = 4444;
public final static String SERVER = "127.0.0.1";
public final static String FILE_TO_RECEIVED = "C:\\file.txt";
public final static int FILE_SIZE = 6022386;
public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
int bytesRead;
int current = 0;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
Socket sock = null;
try {
      sock = new Socket(SERVER, SOCKET_PORT);
      System.out.println("Connecting...");
      // receive file
      byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [FILE_SIZE];
      InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
      fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
      bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
      bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      current = bytesRead;
      do {
         bytesRead =
            is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
         if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
      } while(bytesRead > -1);
      bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
      bos.flush();
      System.out.println("File " + FILE_TO_RECEIVED
          + " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");
    }
    finally {
      if (fos != null) fos.close();
      if (bos != null) bos.close();
      if (sock != null) sock.close();
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is your problem? I see some description what are you going to do and some code only!

Comment: I tried to encrypt the file before sending but didnt work. I try to learn how I can do the encryption in my code.

Comment: *"didnt work"* is not a useful description of your problem. Please show example inputs, outputs and expected outputs. Show stack traces if there are any and correlate them to your code by annotating what the problem lines are.

Comment: How about a Diffie-Helman key exchange?

Comment: The key is generated on the client and server with the same information using SHA256.
I dont need to exchange key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some function I write for you, check it out.

For generating ***HASH/Digest***:

```
public byte[] generateHASH(byte[] message) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest(message);
    return hash;
}
```

For ***Encryption***:

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] msg, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws Exception {
    //prepare key
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    //prepare cipher
    String cipherALG = "AES/CBC/PKCS5padding"; // use your preferred algorithm 
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherALG);
    String string = cipher.getAlgorithm();

    //as iv (Initial Vector) is only required for CBC mode
    if (string.contains("CBC")) {
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);      
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    } else {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    }

    byte[] encMessage = cipher.doFinal(msg);        
    return encMessage;
}
```

For ***Decryption***:

```
public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encMsgtoDec, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws Exception {
    //prepare key
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    //prepare cipher
    String cipherALG = "AES/CBC/PKCS5padding"; // use your preferred algorithm 
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherALG);
    String string = cipher.getAlgorithm();

    //as iv (Initial Vector) is only required for CBC mode
    if (string.contains("CBC")) {
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);      
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    } else {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    }

    byte[] decMsg = cipher.doFinal(encMsgtoDec);        
    return decMsg;
}
```

**Note**:

- If you use CBC mode, then both `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` use same `iv`, otherwise you don't need `iv`, and of course `key` is same for both.
- Your key generation process is naive. You better use RSA public key encryption for key exchange or [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) method for secret key transfer.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! Can you explain to me how I can apply the encryption function to my code? To encrypt the file.

Comment: @Atila, before sending `mybytearray`, just call the `encrypt()` with parameter `mybytearray` as `msg`, thats it! Then send the `encMessage`.

Comment: After this line: bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); ? What I put in the iv parameter?

Comment: Are you gonna use _CBC_ mode or _ECB_ mode? _CBC_ mode requires `iv` where _ECB_ doesn't. But it is recomended to use _CBC_ mode. Moreover, `iv` must be same for both `encrypt()` and `decrypt()`. And yes, before you sending the `mybytearray`, just encrypt it.

Comment: I think in my case CBC is better but im not a expert.
encrypt(mybytearray,key,CBC); equal for decrypt?

Comment: And y u no study more about AES encryption? Start from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

Comment: Look, first generate _KEY_ by calling `generateHASH(byte[] message)` where `message` is the byte representation of string `fruit`, ok? And store the _KEY_ into variable `theKey`. Then call `encrypt(byte[] mybytearray, byte[] theKey, byte[] iv)` where `iv` is a byte array of length `16` withe value `0` cause you are a beginner. Ta da! Done. Soon you will know how to use `iv` then use it in the fullest sense.

Comment: After that line I have to call the function encrypt? and for decrypt()?

Comment: I've studied the benefits of CBC and ECB. For me the most appropriate seemed to me the CBC. I intend to do the "hash" to a string. But to use the hash function must be like "byte []". Any sugestion ?
byte[] key = password.getBytes();
byte[] theKey = generateHASH(key);
encrypt(mybytearray,theKey,iv);

Comment: how can I add the initialize IV random? And use correctly on decrypt funcion?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use SSL. The data encryption comes by default. The SSL handshake takes care of generating and exchanging the encryption keys and subsequently encrypting the data from the source and decrypting it at the receiving end. All this happens at the transport layer and the application does not have to bother or do anything explicit except for configuring it to use SSL.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In my case I really need to use AES-256